# Load x2js Dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi can any body share the link for x2js,
  I want to load this js file dynamically.

I followed the below code its not working

```
EffectaJQ.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "https://x2js.googlecode.com/hg/xml2json.js",
        dataType: "script"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load it on page load, use this

```
var my_script = document.createElement('script');
my_script.setAttribute('src','https://x2js.googlecode.com/hg/xml2json.js');
my_script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
document.head.appendChild(my_script);
```

Or if you want to load it on some event put this code inside some function and call that function on event.